# Can this many-to-many table be improved?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am creating a database where a user can add many books. And a book can be read by many users. I'm using PostgreSQL and set up the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    uid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    hash TEXT NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(30),
    last_name VARCHAR(80)
);

CREATE TABLE books(
    bid VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    author VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    thumbnail TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE users_books(
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    book_id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    date_added DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, book_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(uid) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books(bid) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

As I'm not very familiar with databases, I have the following questions:

1. In the `users_books` table, does the use of `PRIMARY KEY (user_id, book_id)` dispense with the use of `user_id` column or is it still mandatory?
2. Is there any way to auto-populate a table according to the information received by another table? For example, if I feed the users and books tables, can the users_books table feed itself?
3. Is it recommended that I use 3 tables to achieve this goal of people adding books? Or the most recommendable would be to use 2 tables?

Finally, I would like to know what you would do differently from this.

Comment: In this community, and on StackExchange in general, it is better to ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your first question, but I'll give it a shot. The business rule:

A user can add 0 or 1 book would imply a constraint like:

```
ALTER TABLE users_books PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
```

On the other hand, a rule like:

Each book can be added by 0 or 1 users, would imply a constraint like:

```
ALTER TABLE users_books PRIMARY KEY (book_id)
```

If the rule is that a user can add a book 0 or 1 time, even if the book is already added by some other user, the rule would be:

```
ALTER TABLE users_books PRIMARY KEY (user_id, book_id)
```

If the user can add the same book once a day, include date_added in the constraint.

So the answer is, it depends on what BR you would like to implement.

From your description, I would have guessed that that there are two verbs involved:

1. Add_book
2. Read_book

The first would typically be an attribute of the books table:

```
CREATE TABLE books(
    bid VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    author VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    thumbnail TEXT,
    added_by_user ... references users (uid)
);
```

The second would typically be implemented the way you have

The answer to 2 is probably not. The relation represents which users added which books. There is normally no way to figure that out, without the content of user_books table. If user_books is just a cartesian product between users and books, you can replace it with a view:

```
CREATE VIEW users_books as
SELECT u.uid AS user_id, b.bid AS bookid
FROM users u
CROSS JOIN books b
```

I think I have answered 3) so I'll add some thoughts

- If possible use well-established standards. In your case, you may consider using ISBN to identify a book
- Use the same identifiers throughout the model. If you are using uid as an identifier for a user, stick with that identifier in other tables in the model
- Try to find meaningful names for your relations. If user_books represents which books have been read by which users. Try to come up with a name that reflects that.

My two cents on how to design a good primary key / unique constraint

It should be:

- Unique -- of course
- Familiar -- it should be something that exists in your business
- Irreduceble -- No subset of the columns should be unique
- Stable -- It should not change frequently
- Non-complex -- It should not consist of too many columns

Often one can not satisfy all of these and one has to choose one over another. Familiar vs Non-complex is often at the stake (I don't normally consider 2 columns too complex).

It might make sense to add a surrogate attribute that can serve as a primary key but don't do this, as a rule of thumb, make a conscious decision.

If you get to the point that the best option is to use a surrogate key, make sure that you add a unique constraint (sometimes referred to as an alternate key) for the natural key.

Comment: In the 1st one, I meant if using `PRIMARY KEY (user_id, book_id)` does it already create a column with a primary key? Or if I really need to declare a column with primary key. About adding books, I meant that the user can add as many books as he wants (even on the same day), he just can't add the same book more than once. In general, this last table only serves to join the other two, correct?

Comment: No, there is nothing that requires that a primary key consists of one column. Adding such an attribute in your case makes no sense. I'll add some notes on my thoughts on how to design a primary key

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and your explanations!! Thank you very much!!